# Recursive SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

In a table `reviewers` with a structure like this:

```
reviewer | reviewee
===================
2        |      1
3        |      2
4        |      3
5        |      4
```

In a function call, I know both a `reviewer-id` and a `reviewee-id` (the owner of the item the reviewee is looking to retrieve).

I'm now trying to send a query that iterates all the entries in the reviewers table, starting with the reviewer, and ends at the reviewee's id (and matches that to the reviewee id I know). So I'm trying to find out if there is a connection between reviewee and reviewer at all.

Is it possible to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT reviewer, reviewee
   FROM TableName 
   WHERE reviewee = @revieweeID
   UNION ALL
   SELECT p.reviewer, p.reviewee 
   FROM CTE c
   INNER JOIN TableName p ON c.reviewee = p.reviewer
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE;
--- WHERE reviewer = @reviewerID;
```

### [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/89270/recursive-sql-server-query)

Comment: You should start putting the statement terminator (semicolon) at the end of the statement (where it belongs), not at the start: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/post/yet-another-semicolon-rule-in-sql-server-denali.aspx  or https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons