# Parent-Children T-SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, parent-child

I have following DB schema

Location Table

```
LocationID   LocationName
1         |   L1
2         |   L2
.         |   L3
.         |   L4
.         |   L5  
n         |   Ln
```

and another table that defines the parent child relationship and the schema is

```
ID    LocationID    ParentID
1       1            null
2       2            1
3       3            1
4       4            2
```

and so on.

I want to pass in the ID or multiple IDs of the elements at any level and the query returns all the children of the element(s).

Comment: Seems to be a case for [recursive CTEs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933255/recursive-sql-server-query)

Comment: yes. it should be a recursive CTE.

Comment: Do you need all children at all levels or only direct descendants? Because in the second case I think you would not need to use CTE.

Comment: I need all the children at all levels so in other words up to leaf nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select l.LocationID,l.LocationName,m.LocationID AS Child,l1.LocationName AS ChildName
from Location l
inner join mappingtable m
ON l.LocationID=m.ParentID
inner join Location l1
ON l1.LocationID=m.LocationID
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76107/1)

Comment: Thanks for replying but how this will return the result I am looking for?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. Updated the answer. IS that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your post. Is it possible to provide Id or Ids so that I can find children of an element at any level.So if I pass in the ID of top most root its gives me all its children if I pass in the ID of an element say at level 3 it gives my children at level 4 and so on?

Comment: This will not find all levels of children

Comment: Indeed, if this solved your problem you need to rephrase your question as it does not seem to match this answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @relation table(ID int, LocationID int, ParentID int)
insert @relation values
(1,1,null),(2,2,1),(3,3,1),(4,4,2)

declare @Location table (LocationID int,    LocationName varchar(3))
insert @Location values
(1,'L1'),(2,'L2'),(3,'L3'),(4,'L4'),(5,'L5'),(6,'L6')

;with a as
(
select ID p, ID, LocationID, ParentID from @relation where parentid is null
union all
select a.p, t.ID, t.LocationID, t.ParentID
from a join @relation t
on a.ID = t.ParentID
)
select L1.LocationID ParentID, L1.LocationName ParentName, L2.LocationID, L2.LocationName  from a
join @Location L1
on a.p = L1.LocationID
join @Location L2
on a.id = L2.LocationID
option (maxrecursion 500)
```

Result:

```
ParentID  ParentName LocationID LocationName
1         L1         1          L1
1         L1         2          L2
1         L1         3          L3
1         L1         4          L4
```